# Программировние

Tags: книги, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте коллеги.

Я очень хочу изучать программирование, но боюсь запутаться. Подскажите пожалуйста литературу для изучения программирования, пентестинга . Прошу отнестись с пониманием.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -4):

Добрый день! Могу посоветовать пройти какой-нибудь видеокурс по веб-программированию из-разряда "Создание сайта с нуля", вам сразу дадут что-нибудь поделать ручками, немного и ненавязчиво расскажут об основах. Вы сможете понять, какое направление в веб-разработке вам нравится больше. На мой взгляд - это будет полезнее, чем сразу упереться в какое-нибудь "Полное руководство по ..." Вот тут немного ресурсов, где можно начать обучение по видеоурокам:

(на английском)

https://www.codeschool.com/

https://www.codecademy.com/

(на русском)

https://htmlacademy.ru/

https://geekbrains.ru/

https://ru.hexlet.io/

Почти везде есть бесплатные курсы для начинающих. Еще могу посоветовать пройти что-нибудь вроде http://www.wisdomweb.ru/

Безусловно, это не отменяет чтение книг. Но позволит вам мотивировать себя и поможет не бросить на пол дороги.

P.S. Нисколько не претендую на то, что это единственно правильное решение)